# question about AVRO specification and creating a simple REST endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, avro

I have a Rails endpoint like this:

professionals/123/featured_articles

where we do a POST and GET. I'm looking into creating an AVRO .avdl file but am not sure how it should be created. I have:

```
@namespace("API")

protocol Professional {

  record Professional{
    /** The primary key */
    int id;
  }

}
```

Is there a way to specify a custom endpoint like in Rails where it is:

```
/professionals/:professional_id/featured_articles
```

It seems like all of our AVRO endpoints are specified at a single depth and not sure why? Maybe I'm missing something about the overall goal of AVRO. I have worked with Protocol Buffers before so familiar with most of the concepts but not sure about our endpoint generation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is AVRO and how does it related to RoR?

Comment: like Thrift or Protocol Buffers - it's a Rails app; apache subproject

Comment: Like Thrift-RPC or gRPC, I don't think those support "nested routes" either. Instead you'd just have a protocol method like `array<Article> getFeaturedArticlesById(int id)`

Comment: thx @OneCricketeer - I think you're right - it turns out the only thing we were using for was some documentation piece so just kept nested routes and didn't do Avro piece.  A bit of an old system. Thx!